# Read the entire file into this area allocated on the heap

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to open and read two bmp files through command line arguments. After I malloc the size for the  char * I get lost, the `fread()` does not work very well. What's wrong with my code

Here is what I have:

```
void processFileDate(int a, char  **argv, unsigned long size) {

    if(a != 3)
        return;
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    f1 = fopen(*++argv,"rb");
    f2 = fopen(*++argv,"rb");
    if(f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) {
        printf("Can not open file \n");
        return;
    }
    unsigned char *p1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(size + 1);
    unsigned char *p2 = (unsigned char*)malloc(size + 1);

    fread(&p1, 1, size, f1);
    fread(&p2, 1, size, f2);
```

Comment: `the fread() does not works very well ` Can you be more specific here?

Comment: i am using xcode first of all there is a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS second the p1 and p2 got nothing from using fread()

Comment: `&p1` in `fread(&p1, 1, size, f1);` is incorrect. You are giving address of a pointer, not address stored in pointer. It should be plain `p1` instead.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: if only one of the files cannot be opened, your code fails to close the FILE pointer of the other one. And possibly you don't check if the program has been invoked with two arguments.

Comment: `f1 = fopen(*++argv,"rb");` is overly confusing. `f1 = fopen(argv[1],"rb"); f2 = fopen(argv[2],"rb");` is a lot easier to understand.  Confusing code leads to bugs you can't find.  And `if(f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) ...` doesn't tell you which file failed to open - also making problems harder to find.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the signature of the function `fread()`:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

As you can see, its first parameter is a pointer. In your code, you define `p1` and `p2` as pointers to `unsigned char`, but you passed their addresses to `fread()`. This is wrong; you should pass them by value, like the following:

```
fread(p1, 1, size, f1);
fread(p2, 1, size, f2);
```

Comment: one more question since i store the bmp file in the p1 p2 how can i get the width and height for the bmp file

Comment: @YunhanTu you can ask this as a formal question by pressing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, as this is unrelated to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

fread takes a void *ptr, not a void **ptr:

```
if(a != 3)
    return;
FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
f1 = fopen(*++argv,"rb");
f2 = fopen(*++argv,"rb");
if(f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) {
    printf("Can not open file \n");
    return;
}
unsigned char *p1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(size + 1);
unsigned char *p2 = (unsigned char*)malloc(size + 1);



fread(p1, 1, size, f1);
fread(p2, 1, size, f2);
```